# Is it possible to fake a higher resolution?

Tags: display, graphics-card, resolution

I have a laptop running Windows 8. whose monitor can only display up to 1366 by 768. However, I know that my Intel Integrated Graphics card can display up to 1920 by 1080. I wish to force my resolution to 1920 by 1080.

That is, if I were to take a screenshot of my laptop and then transfer the screenshot to a computer whose monitor can display 1920 by 1080, the screenshot will appear as if it is actually 1920 by 1080.

I do not care how it looks on the monitor of my laptop, so long as it looks fine on the monitor of a 1920 by 1080 computer.

Is this possible?

Comment: On a side note from the answer below which is correct, you'd need to edit the image in a graphics application like Photoshop to attain that resolution.

Comment: You didn't specify what kind of operating system you're using. On Linux-based ones, you could use `xrandr` to create and activate a custom mode for your graphics card, even if it doesn't match any of the modes advertised by your screen (see [the example section of the `xrandr` man page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html#toc6) for details). You'd likely end up with a black screen or a "No signal detected" OSD, but you could take your screenshot and switch back to a working mode afterwards.

Comment: @n.st Sorry about that. I am on Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot increase your resolution higher than your monitor can handle.

While there are some monitors and drivers around that can allow you to increase the desktop size while keeping the actual monitor resolution at the maximum (so you'd just scroll across the desktop with your mouse), the general rule is that *Windows will not allow you to increase your resolution above your monitor's (detected) native resolution*.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to get my desired results without actually increasing my resolution then? (To take a screenshot and have it appear as if it was actually taken on 1920 by 1080)

Comment: @user461546 You could try connecting your laptop with your television or monitor if you really want higher resolution. But don't worry about it, as long as your program's window fits in your monitor then you can take a good screenshot of just the window, and nobody will mind.

Answer (score 1):

Yep you can, you have to make a new resolution , cause its not going to show,  when you right click . and use display settings,  also is not going to show on nvidia control panel (idk about amd)

```
    go to nvidia control panel, CHANGE RESOLUTION -> CUSTOMIZE ->
 ENABLE RESOLUTIONS NOT EXPOSED -> CREATE CUSTOM RESOLUTION -> 1920 X 1080
```

then it should appear.   im using 1600 x 900 monitor, Doing this i can record video at 1920 X 1080,  but of course my monitor only shows 1600 x 900.  but if i upload the video to youtube, it actually looks like 1920 x 1080.  so the pc thinks/Displays  1080p.